# Illegal offset type in isset or empty Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I use the following query to get Project Id and Id of Particular Table in Laravel.

```
$projectlist = Projects::Where('customer',$request->input('client_name'))->pluck(DB::raw("CONCAT('project_prefix','project_nos') AS projectid"),"id");
```

**I got following Error.**

```
message Illegal offset type in isset or empty
exception   ErrorException
file    /var/www/msstone/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php
```

Project Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Projects extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    protected $table = 'projects';

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by changing the eloquent query from:

```
$projectlist=Projects::Where('customer',$request->input('client_name'))->pluck(DB::raw("CONCAT('project_prefix','project_nos') AS projectid"),"id");
```

to

```
$projectlist = Projects::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(project_prefix,project_nos) AS projectid"),'id')->where('customer',$request->input('client_name'))->pluck("projectid","id");
```

Comment: Its return "project_prefixproject_nos"

Comment: What are you getting with `dd($projectlist)`?

Comment: <span class=sf-dump-key>1</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="25 characters">project_prefixproject_nos</span>"
    <span class=sf-dump-key>2</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="25 characters">project_prefixproject_nos</span>"
    <span class=sf-dump-key>3</span> => "<span class=sf-dump-str title="25 characters">project_prefixproject_nos</span>"

Comment: Provide your `Projects` model code. And also `projects` database table.

Comment: Add `database table` or `migration` file for `projects` table as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196685/discussion-between-dhananjay-kyada-and-karthik).